# Нужно оттолкнуть нижний элемент от верхнего

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

есть блок, который абсолютно позиционирован по середине, внутри есть заголовок, текст и кнопка, мне нужно оттолкнуть кнопу от текста, пытаюсь это сделать внешними отступами или нижними задавая то "margin-bottom: 66px" верхнему элементу, то "padding-top: 66px" нижнему (кнопке), элементы то отталкиваются, но главный блок, в котором содержатся элементы "плывет вверх".

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="`Arthur Poletaev">
    <meta name="description" content="#">
    <title>ActiveBox</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/019-quora.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="header__nav">
                <div class="header__nav-logo">
                    <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="ActiveBox">
                </div>
                <ul class="header__nav-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Features
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Works
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Team
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Testimonials
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Download
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="header__offer">
                <h1>
                    Your Favorite One Page
                    Multi Purpose Template
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna
                    vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
                </p>
                <p class="header__offer-btn">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">
                        Find Out More
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="features">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="works">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="team">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="testimonials">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="download">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    color: #6c7279;
    height: 100%;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul, li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, p {
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    line-height: 71px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #2d3033;
}

.visuali-hidden {

}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

/* =============== Header =============== */

.header {
    background: #2a2e48 url(../img/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(42, 46, 72, 0.9);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.header__nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 45px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #505369;
}

.header__nav-menu {
    display: flex;`
}


.header__nav-menu li + li{
    margin-left: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

.header__nav-menu li + li::before {
    content: '';
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: -33px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}



.header__nav-menu a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    position: relative;
}

.header__nav-menu a::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.header__nav-menu a:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.header__nav-menu a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

.header__offer {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 917px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header__offer p {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 33px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Судя по вашему коду, ничего там не плывет. Блок - header__offer- позиционирован по центру. Вы даёте, внутри, больше отступа (margin/padding), он просто становится больше по высоте и забирает место как сверху (то что вы называете "плывёт"), так и снизу

Comment: Ну как вариант, возможно, вам подойдёт задать элементу .btn позиционирование relative ну и дать ему top, например. єто решит вашу задачу, правда может создать некоторые неудобства при вёрстке для последующих элементов. А может и нет. Не знаю, что там у вас дальше будет.

Comment: Спасибо. помогли

Comment: Дам еще совет, для боди и хтмл используйте min-height, меньше потом проблем будет неожиданных.

Comment: А на Safari с min-height проблем может стать больше.